# How to configure Codacy Python linters?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, codacy

I recently enabled GitHub Codacy scans on my repo. The Pylint* and Prospector modules (if that is the right terminology) report a lot of warnings:
[image]

I have to believe there's a way to configure what they flag, perhaps via an `rc` file or a `.yml` placed *somewhere*, but I haven't figured out what the config files should be named, where they should be placed, and what the allowable syntax(es) are.  I'd be happy to RTFM if I could figure out the FM to R.

How do I configure the linters invoked by Codacy code scanners on GitHub?

Comment: maybe it helps: https://blog.codacy.com/configuring-codacy-use-your-own-conventions/

Comment: if I remember correctly if you add a linter configuration file, codacy would pick it up (for instance, ruby rubocop expects a .rubocop file on the root folder. If it exists, codacy uses it)

Answer (score 0):

Codacy will pick up the default config files for each linter.

Prospector (http://prospector.landscape.io/en/master/profiles.html#profiles-configuration)

```
.landscape.yml, .landscape.yaml, landscape.yml, landscape.yaml,
.prospector.yml, .prospector.yaml, prospector.yml, prospector.yaml
```

Pylint (http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-find-the-option-name-for-pylintrc-corresponding-to-a-specific-command-line-option)

```
pylintrc, .pylintrc
```

You can check Codacy's docs here for the details of more tools:
https://docs.codacy.com/repositories-configure/code-patterns/#i-have-my-own-tool-configuration-file

Also, if you set up your project in Codacy's APP, you can also configure those patterns in the settings instead of using a config files.